# How to save and retrieve the investors address in a crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, myetherwallet, ico, airdrop

I am writing a ICO code which should have the following functionalities

1. To save the address of every investor and
2. To retrieve all the investors address and the amount invested

**Question**

1. What is the best way to do it ? Any code snippet will be a great help.
2. Lets assume there are 30000 investors.

   2.a Is it possible to save those in the state variable ?

   2.b Is it possible to get all the 30000 investor address and their amount using any online tool like MEW / Etherscan.io (Read contract) ?

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, this is rather trivial to implement. Something like this:

```
contract Test {

   address[] investors;
   mapping(address => uint256) private balances;

   function saveAddress() payable public {
       investors.push(msg.sender);
       balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
   }
}
```

Here `msg.sender` refers to the one who is sending the contract Ether and `msg.value` is the amount of Ether sent. Note that your function has to be `payable` to be able to receive Ethers.

If you don't need to be able to retrieve the list of investors, you can even drop the `investors` variable - `balances` mapping will contain investment information per investor, but you can't get a list of investors from it.

For reading you don't need any code in your contract - all data in smart contracts is directly readable even without any explicit code. You can use any web3 library for it.

Saving 30000 addresses with their balances will cost some gas. But if the data is stored whenever someone invests in the ICO, the gas cost is payed by the investor so you don't really need to worry about that.

And yes, you can use also any online tool like MEW/Etherscan to read the data.

Comment: While retreving from MEW / Etherscan.. will it return all the 30000 address..

Comment: Will there be any be I while retreving such huge data online

Comment: I guess retrieval will give you all the data at once, but not 100% sure about this - will depend also on which service you use. Read documentation of the respective services to find out how they actually provide the data.

Comment: Sorry to add it now..   I need both address and their amount

Comment: Modified answer to suit your needs.

Comment: The balances variable is a mapping variable. It will return the amount if I pass the address.. but I need all the investor address and their amount..      do u mean I have to get the list of investors from the variable "investors" and I have to iterate 30000 times on the variable "balances". Please advice

Comment: Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Comments section is not suited for answering questions. If you have further questions which are not covered by an answer, you should post a new question. But, yes, if you want to have a list of who has invested, you need to have an `investors` variable..

Comment: The Read contract list the address from "investors" based on the index that we are providing. Any way to get all at once ?